# Facebook share shows blank image on iOS but works fine on desktop

Tags: ios, facebook, addthis

I am using AddThis from the following page: http://www.douglasstratton.com/Beaches/Amnesia/flypage.tpl.html

When sharing from the desktop, the image shares fine, but when sharing from iOS, the image is blank on the facebook wall.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can share with this code.Only import #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>:-
  // Put together the dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   APP_NAME, @"name",
                                   self.strSerialName , @"caption",
                                   modelObject.strChapterDescription, @"description",
                                   @"", @"link",
                                   modelObject.strChapterImage, @"picture",
                                   nil];
    // Show the feed dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                      NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                          NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                          if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                              // User cancelled.
                                                              NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                          } else {
                                                              // User clicked the Share button
                                                              NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                              NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }];
```